# R Shiny: Update datatable with checkbox

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I want to dynamically populate a table and update a list of items selected using the checkbox.

Here is my attempt. I report some random data points into a table and uncheck some of them expecting the list at the bottom of the plot to change.

The list is correctly updated only when unchecking the last item but not the others.

Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
    column(4,
        plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
        textInput("collection_txt",label="Foo")),
    column(4,
    DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
    )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

    # collect data points

    x <- reactiveValues(selected = '')
    y <- reactiveValues(selected = '')
    observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
        x$x <- c(x$x,input$plot_click$x)
        y$y <- c(y$y,input$plot_click$y)
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        plot(1,1, type='n')
        points(x$x,y$y)
    })

    # populate the table

    shinyInput <- function(FUN,id,num,...) {
        inputs <- character(num)
        for (i in seq_len(num)) {
            inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id,i),label=NULL,...))
        }
        inputs
    }

    output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
        tab <- data.frame('x'=x$x ,'y'=y$y)
        DT::datatable(cbind(tab, Selected=shinyInput(checkboxInput,"srows_",nrow(tab),value=TRUE,width=1)),
                                options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,
                                   drawCallback= JS(
                                     'function(settings) {
                                     Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
                                   dom = 't', searching=FALSE),
                                selection='none',escape=F)
    })

    # show the list of selected items

    rowSelect <- reactive({
      rows=names(input)[grepl(pattern = "srows_",names(input))]
      paste(unlist(lapply(rows,function(i){
        if(input[[i]]==T){
          return(substr(i,gregexpr(pattern = "_",i)[[1]]+1,nchar(i)))
        }
      })))
    })

    observe({
      updateTextInput(session, "collection_txt", value = rowSelect() ,label = "Selected:" )
    })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What are you doing here? `rows=names(input)[grepl(p...` what is `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unbind the previously created Shiny objects before creating the new table, when you click on a point. For example with `shinyjs`:

```
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    ......


  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    runjs("Shiny.unbindAll($('#table').find('table').DataTable().table().node());")
    x$x <- c(x$x,input$plot_click$x)
    y$y <- c(y$y,input$plot_click$y)
  })
```

[image]